# Setting up JDBC authentication in Vaadin without an HTML login page

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, vaadin

I'd like to set up user authentication on my Vaadin application, but I do not want to authenticate with an HTML or JSP page. I want to write code using the Vaadin API to capture the username & password and to feed it to Glassfish using more Java code. So far, I have successfully retrieved a username and password from the user using this (basic) code:

```
@Title("test")
@Theme("valo")
public class MyVaadinApplication extends UI {
    private String user;
    private String pwd;

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = false)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinApplication.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        FormLayout form = new FormLayout();
        setContent(form);

        TextField nameField = new TextField("Name:");
        PasswordField passField = new PasswordField("Password:");
        Button button = new Button("Login");

        form.addComponent(nameField);
        form.addComponent(passField);
        form.addComponent(button);

        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                user = nameField.getValue();
                pwd = passField.getValue();
                Notification.show("Name=" + user +  ", PWD=" + pwd, Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now I am trying to use the user/pass Strings to login, but I can't seem to find a means of doing so. I found this amazing document that outlines exactly what I need (found here: https://blogs.oracle.com/bobby/entry/authentication_without_the_form), but unfortunately it's pretty outdated and the code is no longer there. I tried searching for the "getRequest().login()" method that was used but can't find any Vaadin class that supports it. Has anyone ever done this before? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your login operation will redirect the user to a different page/view.

You can always pass attributes between views using the session's `setAttribute` function:

```
getUI().getSession().setAttribute("username", user);
```

Then you can retrieve this attribute on the next view so that you can determine if the user has logged in or not.

```
getUI().getSession().getAttribute("username");
```

I'm not sure where you're storing the accounts but whatever you use (database, text file, etc.) this way should be valid.

I advise you look into VaadinSession since the session practically stores every data you need until it expires.

Here are some links that might help:

[VaadinSession documentation](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html)

[Setting and reading session attributes](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Setting+and+reading+session+attributes)

Try these out and I can provide more help if you need.

Comment: I actually realized that it was the HttpServletRequest that was doing the actual login in that example, but you've provided some helpful documentation!

Comment: Glad I could help, I'm actually doing a similar project with Hibernate & Tomcat, so if you need any other help just ask. :)

Comment: Do you think you can clarify how getting & setting the attributes will help authenticate? I revisited your answer today, and I am trying to implement what you said. I am trying to use a JDBC user/pw table and a JDBC group table to authenticate users based on group. I know how to authenticate using a user-defined HTML page (FORM authentication), but I can't figure out how I would accomplish the same thing with plain ol' Java code. Thanks!

Comment: @Niko Sure I can. You can pass attributes between views. Consider views as pages. You have a login view and main view. You need to be logged in to have access to main view. You check the attribute in main view. If it's null you don't give access, otherwise you grant access. You set attribute from the login view. Say the user enters a username in login view, (assuming it's unique for every user) then you pass it as the attribute so that logged in user can gain access to main view. That's the basic idea. Of course you can create unique views for each user so they can access their own page.

Comment: Hm okay that makes perfect sense, but the one thing that I still don't understand is how I would verify that the user's username/password combination is a valid one (i.e. in my user/pw database). I do not want to grant access to anyone who provides a username.

Comment: You'll just need to pull the usernames to separate strings and compare them with the entered username when the user clicks the login button.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought there was maybe a designated method or API to handle this, but I guess not. Glassfish has a built in JDBC Realm, which, when used with a FORM login.xhtml page, will automatically cross-reference the entered user/pw combo with your database. I thought there was some way to still utilize this without performing the comparisons myself, but either way, you've been a big help. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're using mysql, Hibernate is a great framework that eliminates any SQL based code directly and makes database operations pure java. Check it out.